# How to permanently teach Visual Studio to detect my debugging information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

Using Visual Studio 2012, maybe you've seen this message, too:

[image]

It says:

> The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information:
>
> *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6dce49fa\6c454827\assembly\dl3\95d61873\9871ffdd_4288ce01\NoeDownloadbereichWeb.dll*
>
> To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug
>   mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on
>   launch' debugger option.

In the past I got this maybe once a week when starting to debug my ASP.NET application and resolved it by simply recompiling my solution.

Recently I switched to IIS Express this now happens every second/third time I want to debug my code after I did some changes.

I resolve it by one or all of the following steps:

- Rebuild my application (helps most of the time)
- Close IIS Express and rebuild my application
- Reboot Windows 8 and rebuild my application

I've found [similar questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952964/built-with-optimizations-enabled-or-without-debug-information) and [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20following%20module%20was%20built%20either%20with%20optimizations%20enabled%20or%20without%20debug%20information) and still am not able to permanently resolve this.

**My question:**

Can you imagine what causes this behaviour every now and then?

**Update 1**

The error seems to be related with/followed by [ASP.NET error messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/06/09/cannot-create-shadow-copy-file-name-when-that-file-already-exists.aspx) like (German):

> Das Erstellen von "System.Net.Http.Extensions" oder das Erstellen einer Schattenkopie ist nicht möglich, wenn diese Datei bereits vorhanden ist.

Which rougly translates to English:

> Cannot create/shadow copy "System.Net.Http.Extensions" when that file already exists.

(The refered file name "System.Net.Http.Extensions" is randomly changed by ASP.NET)

**Update 2**

I've switch back to Visual Studio Development Server and immediately got rid of the errors described above:

[image]

Don't know whether this is just on my system, or what's the reason for it.

Answer (score 15):

Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code > Warn if no user code on launch

[image: tools options screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like this just masks the message box but does not resolve the underlying reason?!?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but I don't think so, because I can still debug the assembly just fine. I'd love to understand fully what is happening, but sometimes you just run out of time :(